# Find Domain and Range of $f(x)=\ln(x^2+4x+5)$?

Tags: logarithms

I think it could be solved by plotting its graph maybe or the equation is wrong here.

Comment: **Hint**: For $\ln(x)$ to be defined, you need $x>0$. Now try to factor $x^2+4x+5$

Comment: roots are (-2+i),(-2-i) so how to solve ahead

Comment: Good. Now you know that there are no real roots, hence the expression inside $\ln()$ is never $0$. Now try to find the smallest possible value for $x^2+4x+5$.

Comment: To find the smallest value, try to write the expression $x^2+4x+5$ on the form $y^2+c$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's refer to the parabola as $p$, i.e. $p(x)=x^2 + 4x + 5$.
Since the coefficient for $x^2$ is 1, which is greater than 0, we have a parabola which is "moving upwards", i.e. it has its absolute minimum at its vertex. The vertex is the point where the derivative $p'$ is equal to 0. And $p'(x) = 2x + 4 = 0$ if and only if $x = -2$. Hence, the coordinates of the vertex and minimum are $(-2, p(-2)) = (-2, 1).$ Hence, the parabola $p$ has range $(1, \infty)$. Since the natural log $ln$ is monotonically increasing on $(0,\infty)$, the minimum value of $f(x) = ln(x^2 + 4x + 5) = ln(p(x))$ is given by $ln(1) = 0$ and it will take all values greater than $0$ as well.
Formally speaking, the image of the polynomial is given by $p(\mathbb{R}) =  [1, \infty)$ and hence the image of $f = ln \circ p$ is given by $ln([1, \infty)) = [0, \infty)$. This answers the range question. (image of a function is another term for range).
As @cansomeonehelpmeout has pointed out, $ln$ is defined for $x > 0$, so since the parabola has minimum value of $1 > 0$, $f(x) = ln(p(x))$ is defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

To summarize: domain of $f$ is given by $\mathbb{R}$, range is given by $[0, \infty)$. Using the derivative of the polynomial made it unncessary to calculate its roots and it allowed us to see that $p(x) = (x+2)^2 + 1$.

Answer (score 0):

$x$ belongs to the whole real field from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$.

$f(x)$ goes from zero to $+\infty$.

$f(-2)=0$

when

$log(x^{2}+4x+5)=log(1)$